# arduino, function to return char array

Tags: c++, c, arduino

```
_10_11.ino: In function 'void loop()':
_10_11:73: error: initializer fails to determine size of 'results'
_10_11.ino: In function 'char getData()':
_10_11:160: error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator+'
```

In short, i have a function `char getData()` which returns `char output[50] = "1: " + cmOne + " 2: " + cmTwo + " 3: " + cmThree + " 4: " + cmFour;` where `int cmOne, cmTwo, cmThree, cmFour`.

In loop, i call:

```
char results[] = getData();

    client.println("1: %i", results[0]);
    client.println("2: %i", results[1]);
    client.println("3: %i", results[2]);
    client.println("4: %i", results[3]);
```

I know that i'm wrong with my data types, assigning etc but am abit off with how to do it best, any suggestions??

Comment: Please decide. Is this question about C or is it about C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible, create a fixed size array, and pass it to the function as a pointer, and initialize it in the function

```
char results[4];

getData(results); /* the getData function should take a 'char *' paramenter */

client.println("1: %i", results[0]);
client.println("2: %i", results[1]);
client.println("3: %i", results[2]);
client.println("4: %i", results[3]);
```

and of course if the array is bigger just `char results[A_BIGGER_SIZE];`

Suppose that get data just puts a string `"ABC"` in the `result` array it would look like

```
void getData(char *dest)
{
    dest[0] = 'A';
    dest[1] = 'B';
    dest[2] = 'C';
    dest[3] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: am i correct to assume that i would make char results[4] global so it can be accessed/assigned outside loop?

Comment: @Simon No, you should just declare it in the same scope of the loop. And if you want it in some other function, just pass it as a pointer to `char *`, and it cannot be assigned anywhere, you can assign to it's elements though.